# Exception parsing string to JSONObject (works at local server, but not at the online server) android

Tags: android, string, json

the code:

```
public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();       
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray hashMap_names = json_data.names();
        JSONArray hashMap_names2 = new JSONArray();
        Map hashMap = new HashMap(json_data.length());
        for (int i=0; i!=hashMap_names.length(); i++){
            //Object obj = chaves.next();
        hashMap.put(String.valueOf(i),json_data.get(String.valueOf(i)));
            hashMap_names2.put(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        JSONObject hashMap_obj = new JSONObject (hashMap);
        jArr = hashMap_obj.toJSONArray(hashMap_names2);
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "succesful parsing data " + jArr.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        jArr = null;
    }

    return jArr;

}
```

after the stringbuilder.toString(), json has the folowwing value:

```
{"0":"27124","1":"Adsad adadda daddadadad ","2":"asdasdas@gmail.com","3":"732bcv874uhfebfehuif9724uhife","4":"wasd","5":"","6":"M","7":"","8":"","9":"","10":"","11":"","12":"06\/05\/1989","13":"","14":"","15":"","16":"","17":"","18":"","19":"","20":"BR","21":"","22":"0","23":"","24":"","25":"","26":"Y","27":"Y","28":"Y","29":"N","30":"0","31":"30\/04\/2012 16:48:20","32":"17\/04\/2012 01:09:27","33":"367","34":"50","35":"0","36":"79","37":"34","38":"","39":"17\/04\/2012 01:16:54","40":"3649","41":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]}
```

wich looks to me a perfect formated JSON text.

but when I try creating a new JSONObject(json), get the exception

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

BUT I only get this error when using the online server. If I use the local one (xammp), json is parsed to JSONObject and the app works.

I've tried to set `json = "{'0':'1212','1':'username','2':'email','3':'pass'}";` and it worked! but when using `json = "\""+json.replace('\"', '\'')+"\"";` just got the same exception

by the way, i'm using the hashmap just to ordenate de JSONObject after parsing.

Maybe the issue its because on local I'm using php 5.3, and the online server uses php 5.2? There is any difference between the headers of these versions? How could I verificate this?

Comment: I recommend replacing all that crazy `InputStream`-and-`BufferedReader` stuff with `json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity)`. This might just fix what appears to be an encoding problem of yours (you assume UTF-8, ignoring whatever the server says).

Comment: first, thanks for the help! I tried the EntityUtils stuff, it worked just fine on local server, but i'm still getting the exception when using the online server. 
But the logcat message now is: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.
So the json had this weird ï»¿ before {"0":"67987","1":"ategdtg tadgtedg ","2":"eytdgaetydg@yaeyedg.com",.......}, what could it be?

Comment: And looking back on the exception before using entityutils, seems that exists a null at json: look above, "JSONException: Value  of type..." . Maybe by removing this i'll get over this problem?

Comment: Could you update your question with the current code and error message? That would make it much easier to follow :)

Comment: I will. btw, the ï»¿ is a BOM: http://rusanu.com/2009/05/21/have-you-met-i%C2%BB%C2%BF-say-hello-to-my-bom/
wondering if i can use BOMInputStream to skip it.

Comment: BOMs and UTF-8 usually just cause trouble. Can you fix the PHP script not to output a BOM? If not, `BOMInputStream` sounds like a good idea.

Comment: BOMInputStream did the job, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
                    OutputStreamWriter request = null;
                    URL url = null;

                     String parameters = "parameter1="+parameter;

                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://myserver.com/samplejson.php");

                        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                        request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                        request.write(parameters);
                        request.flush();
                        request.close();
                        String line = "";
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                                connection.getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }

                        response = sb.toString();
                         ///you will get response here..

                        isr.close();
                        reader.close();

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: This is working for me it get response. parse that json object.